# Laravel: HasManyThrough Polymorphic Problem

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, relationship

Suppose that I have the following tables:

```
users
- id
- name
- email
- password
```

```
posts
- id
- title
- content
- user_id
```

```
pages
- id
- title
- content
- user_id
```

```
commentables
- id 
- body
- user_id
- commentable_id
- commentable_type (post or photo)
```

Then, I create models for each of them: 
User, Post, Page, Commentable

```
// User 
  public function commentables() {
     return $this->hasMany("App\Commentable");
  }

  public function comments_on_posts() {
     // code to get the comments on user's post ?? <- Problem 1
  }

  public function comments_on_pages() { 
     // code to get the comments on user's pages ?? <- Problem 2
  }
```

I need to aggregate/collect all comments for the posts or pages of a certain user (hasManyThrough).

1. **Problem 1**: Collect all comments for the posts of a certain user.
2. **Problem 2**: Collect all comments for the comments of a certain user.

Comment: hello,  have you tried anything yet?  The Laravel docs are a fantastic resource.  https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent

Comment: May I add to this: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships . I think you just need to step by step follow the setup of each individual relationship. After you done and tested that, it will become alot easier.

Comment: Finally, thanks @Nibb and @Rob! I found a section in the docs that helped me.